# Will Old Tab using Static FBML tab be removed

Tags: fbml, share

Reading from "http://developers.facebook.com", they are deprecating FBML. On Jan 1, 2012: FBML will no longer be supported on Platform. June 1, 2012: FBML apps will no longer work. All FBML endpoints are removed.

My question is - will my OLD Static FBML Tabs be diabled and the tab content not accessible?  If yes, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will. (stop working)
Only thing you can do is update your tab applications.  Facebook has given a lot of [warning that FBML is planned to be deprecated and eventually not supported](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/568/).  To the best of my knowledge there is no "quick-fix".  Facebook changes their systems quite often and as developers it is **our** responsibility to keep up to date.

Answer (score 0):

As per the text you copied they'll be removed on or after June 1, 2012. 
Also, if any part of FBML breaks which prevents your apps from working after Jan 1, 2012, it won't be fixed